# Angular application not updating different image types correctly despite correct implementation of onFileSelect method

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm encountering an issue in my Angular application where I'm trying to upload and preview images. I have implemented an onFileSelect method which is called when a file is selected, and depending on the image type, it should update the corresponding property in the data service.

The problem I'm facing is that regardless of which image is uploaded, only the main image seems to be updated, even though I'm confident that the correct image types are being passed.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// bilder-hochladen-dialog.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataserviceService } from '../dataservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bilder-hochladen-dialog',
  templateUrl: './bilder-hochladen-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bilder-hochladen-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class BilderHochladenDialogComponent {

  constructor(public _dataservice: DataserviceService) {}

  onFileSelect(event: Event, imageType: string) {
    const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const file = inputElement.files?.[0];
    const allowedFileTypes = ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg"];
    
    if (file && allowedFileTypes.includes(file.type)) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        switch (imageType) {
          case 'main':
            this._dataservice.MainimgData = reader.result as string;
            break;
          case 'detail1':
            this._dataservice.DetailimgData1 = reader.result as string;
            break;
          // other cases for different detail images
        }
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      console.log("Image could not be converted to data string or file type not allowed");
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the HTML code:

```
<!-- bilder-hochladen-dialog.component.html -->

<div class="DialogBody">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Main Image Upload Section -->
    <div class="Row">
      <div class="col-md">
        <div class="ImageAdderFlex">
          <input class="DefaultInput" id="uploadImg" (change)="onFileSelect($event,'main')" type="file" #fileinput1 name="FileInput">
          <label for="uploadImg" class="UploadButton"> <span>Main Image Upload</span> <img src=".\assets\Icons\Uploadfoto.png"> </label>
          <div class="ImagesFlex">
            <img class="ProductImageVorschauDefault" src=".\assets\Icons\t-shirt.svg">
            <img class="ProductImageVorschau realeImage" [src]="_dataservice.MainimgData">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Detail Image Upload Sections (Repeat for multiple images) -->
    <!-- Adjust the change event and imageType accordingly for each detail image -->
    <!-- Example for detail1 -->
    <div class="Row">
      <div class="col-md">
        <div class="ImageAdderFlex">
          <input class="DefaultInput" id="uploadImg" (change)="onFileSelect($event,'detail1')" type="file" #fileinput1 name="FileInput">
          <label for="uploadImg" class="UploadButton"> <span>Detail Image 1 Upload</span> <img src=".\assets\Icons\Uploadfoto.png"> </label>
          <div class="ImagesFlex">
            <img class="ProductImageVorschauDefault" src=".\assets\Icons\t-shirt.svg">
            <img class="ProductImageVorschau realeImage" [src]="_dataservice.DetailimgData1">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Repeat the above section for other detail images (detail2, detail3, etc.) -->

    <!-- Button to Confirm and Submit Images -->
    <div class="Row">
      <div class="col-md">
        <div class="ImageAdderFlex">
          <div  class="BestaetigenButton"> <span>Confirm</span> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I've double-checked my implementation of the onFileSelect method to ensure the switch block is functioning correctly and that the correct image type is being passed. I've also verified the data service to ensure that the properties for detail images (DetailimgData1, DetailimgData2, etc.) are correctly initialized and updated.

Despite these checks, the issue persists. Are there additional steps I can take to diagnose and resolve this problem? Are there any known limitations or common pitfalls in Angular that